# LogOff ASP NET / HTTPS CAUSA ERRO DE SEGURANÇA

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-service, aplicação-web

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Olá bom dia, possuo uma aplicação asp net, que faz uso da segurança https, no entanto no momento do logoff ele causa umna mensagem de erro, alguém já passou por isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o certificado esta em dia?

Comment: Sim, está tudo certo

Comment: Acontece no momento do logoff - https://ex.dominio.com.br/Acesso/Index?ReturnUrl=%2fHome%2fIndex

Comment: Poste como está o seu método de logof

Comment: public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            SessionHelper.Logout();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

Comment: acredito que o problema é troca de protocolo http para https.